# Move div upwards so parent div moves up as well

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website. I am using margin and `position: relative;` to move stuff around.

I'm working on menu items. I have them stored in a div with the class `col-1`. This div needs to be moved up to the top of the menu section, except when I do this with position relative the column moves up but the orange menu container stays the same height.

How can I make the parent div shrink when there's no content there?

```js
const exit = document.querySelector('.fa-times');
const navBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-btn');
const btn1 = document.querySelector('.btn-1');
const btn2 = document.querySelector('.btn-2');
const btn3 = document.querySelector('.btn-3');
const sideMenu = document.querySelector('.side-menu');
const aboutSection = document.querySelector('#about');
const menuSection = document.querySelector('#menu');
const menuItem = document.querySelector('.item');

exit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  exit.style.left = '-370px';
  sideMenu.style.left = '-370px';
  reverse(btn1);
  reverse(btn2);
  reverse(btn3);

  function reverse(button) {
    button.style.animationName = button.className + '-reverse';
  }

})

navBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sideMenu.style.left = '0px';
  exit.style.left = '380px';
  animate(btn1);
  animate(btn2);
  animate(btn3);

  function animate(button) {
    button.style.animationName = button.className + '-animate';
  }
})

aboutSection.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  const line = document.querySelector('.line');
  line.style.width = '250px';
})

menuSection.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  const line = document.querySelector('.line-2');
  line.style.width = '340px';
  line.style.marginLeft = '170px';
})

// menuItem.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
//  e.
// })

window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.auth', {
  duration: 2000,
  distance: '80px'
});
sr.reveal('.mexi', {
  duration: 2500,
  distance: '80px'
});
sr.reveal('.food', {
  duration: 3000,
  distance: '80px'
});
sr.reveal('.btn-1', {
  duration: 2000,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '100px'
});
sr.reveal('.btn-2', {
  duration: 1500,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '100px'
});
sr.reveal('.btn-3', {
  duration: 1000,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '100px'
});
sr.reveal('.left', {
  duration: 1500,
  origin: 'bottom',
  distance: '100px'
});
sr.reveal('.right', {
  duration: 1500,
  origin: 'bottom',
  distance: '100px'
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*HEADER*/

#header {
  background: url('img/mex-9.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.btn-1,
.btn-2,
.btn-3 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 62px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btn-1-animate {
  from {
    width: 62px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    top: 75px;
    left: -12px;
    width: 84px;
  }
}

@keyframes btn-1-reverse {
  from {
    top: 75px;
    left: -12px;
    width: 84px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 62px;
  }
}

.btn-2 {
  border-radius: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes btn-2-animate {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 62px
  }
  to {
    top: 58px;
    left: 65px;
    width: 117px;
  }
}

@keyframes btn-2-reverse {
  from {
    top: 58px;
    left: 65px;
    width: 117px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 62px;
  }
}

.btn-3 {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btn-3-animate {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 62px;
  }
  to {
    top: 41px;
    left: 180px;
    width: 140px;
  }
}

@keyframes btn-3-reverse {
  from {
    top: 41px;
    left: 180px;
    width: 140px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 62px;
  }
}

.side-menu,
.nav-btn {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.nav-btn {
  width: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#header ul {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: -15px 0px lightgreen;
}

.side-menu {
  position: relative;
  left: -370px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fa-times {
  position: fixed;
  left: -380px;
  top: 200px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.fa-times:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#header li a {
  font-family: 'Kumar One Outline';
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding: 15px;
  color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#header li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

#header li {
  margin: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

#header li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #96ea96;
}

#header p {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
}


/*ABOUT*/

#about .container {
  background-color: #339966;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: -400px;
}

#about h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.line {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 0px;
  height: 4px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 560px;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#about p {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  width: 35%;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.image-slider {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 35%;
  height: 250px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -380px;
  float: right;
}

.fa-caret-down {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-top: 29%;
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: -40px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  left: 40px;
}


/*MENU*/

#menu .container {
  background-color: #e6ac00;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-top: -330px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 10%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.shape-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.shape-1 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #339966;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: -190px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.shape-2 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 10px;
}

.shape-3 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #40bf80;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  left: -195px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 25px;
}

.shape-4 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 85px;
}

.shape-5 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #339966;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  left: -298px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 110px;
}

.shape-6 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #339966;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 230px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -351px;
}

.shape-7 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -90px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 265px;
}

.shape-8 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #339966;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 290px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -405px;
}

.shape-9 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -140px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 325px;
}

.shape-10 {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #40bf80;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  left: -410px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 325px;
}

#menu h1 {
  font-size: 7rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  margin-left: 220px;
  position: relative;
  top: -280px;
  left: -40px;
}

.line-2 {
  background-color: #339966;
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 470px;
  position: relative;
  top: -435px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.platter {
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  color: #339966;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.platter-info {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  color: white;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.item {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.price {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  display: block;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.col-1 {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: static;
  top: -400px;
}

.plat-4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 120px;
}

.info4tacos {
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.plat-7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}

.plat-8 {
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
}

.plat-9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}

.info4breakfast {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}

.col-2 {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>El Metate | Mexican Food</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive|Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif|Kumar+One+Outline|Teko" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Diplomata+SC|Ewert|Sarina|Smokum" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-btn">
        <div class="btn-1"></div>
        <div class="btn-2"></div>
        <div class="btn-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side-menu">
        <ul>
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#hours">Hours</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p><span class="auth">Authentic</span><span class="mexi">Mexican</span><span class="food">Food</span></p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <h1>About us</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, quis, adipisci! Unde natus quas officiis, earum commodi! Voluptate in modi alias quisquam maiores sunt fugit reprehenderit odio rem obcaecati libero repellat saepe quidem quibusdam
        impedit labore error velit, possimus necessitatibus. Optio ullam, officiis, sit ipsa fugiat animi voluptas labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, et.</p>
      <div class="image-slider">
        <i class="fas fa-caret-down left"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-caret-down right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="shape-wrap">
        <span class="shape-1"></span>
        <span class="shape-2"></span>
        <span class="shape-3"></span>
        <span class="shape-4"></span>
        <span class="shape-5"></span>
        <span class="shape-6"></span>
        <span class="shape-7"></span>
        <span class="shape-8"></span>
        <span class="shape-9"></span>
        <span class="shape-10"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 385px;">
        <span class="shape-1"></span>
        <span class="shape-2"></span>
        <span class="shape-3"></span>
        <span class="shape-4"></span>
        <span class="shape-5"></span>
        <span class="shape-6"></span>
        <span class="shape-7"></span>
        <span class="shape-8"></span>
        <span class="shape-9"></span>
        <span class="shape-10"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 770px;">
        <span class="shape-1"></span>
        <span class="shape-2"></span>
        <span class="shape-3"></span>
        <span class="shape-4"></span>
        <span class="shape-5"></span>
        <span class="shape-6"></span>
        <span class="shape-7"></span>
        <span class="shape-8"></span>
        <span class="shape-9"></span>
        <span class="shape-10"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1155px;">
        <span class="shape-1"></span>
        <span class="shape-2"></span>
        <span class="shape-3"></span>
        <span class="shape-4"></span>
        <span class="shape-5"></span>
        <span class="shape-6"></span>
        <span class="shape-7"></span>
        <span class="shape-8"></span>
        <span class="shape-9"></span>
        <span class="shape-10"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1540px;">
        <span class="shape-1"></span>
        <span class="shape-2"></span>
        <span class="shape-3"></span>
        <span class="shape-4"></span>
        <span class="shape-5"></span>
        <span class="shape-6"></span>
        <span class="shape-7"></span>
        <span class="shape-8"></span>
        <span class="shape-9"></span>
        <span class="shape-10"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1925px;">
        <span class="shape-1"></span>
        <span class="shape-2"></span>
        <span class="shape-3"></span>
        <span class="shape-4"></span>
        <span class="shape-5"></span>
        <span class="shape-6"></span>
        <span class="shape-7"></span>
        <span class="shape-8"></span>
        <span class="shape-9"></span>
        <span class="shape-10"></span>
      </div>


      <h1>Menu</h1>
      <div class="line-2"></div>

      <div class="vexel-images"></div>

      <div class="col-1">
        <h3 class="platter">Combination Platters</h3>
        <p class="platter-info">Rice & Beans Included</p>

        <p class="item item-1">Tostada & Taco</p><span class="price p1"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
        <p class="item item-2">2 Beef Tacos</p><span class="price p2"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
        <p class="item item-3">2 Enchiladas</p><span class="price p3"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
        <p class="item item-4">Tostada & Enchilada</p><span class="price p4"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
        <p class="item item-5">Taco & Enchilada</p><span class="price p5"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
        <p class="item item-6">Burrito & Enchilada</p><span class="price p6"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
        <p class="item item-7">2 Beef Burritos</p><span class="price p7"><span class="s1">$</span>7.45</span>
        <p class="item item-8">2 Carne Asada Tacos</p><span class="price p8"><span class="s1">$</span>8.09</span>
        <p class="item item-9">Chorizo</p><span class="price p9"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
        <p class="item item-10">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p10"><span class="s1">$</span>8.19</span>
        <p class="item item-11">Machaca</p><span class="price p11"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
        <p class="item item-12">Carnitas</p><span class="price p12"><span class="s1">$</span>7.19</span>
        <p class="item item-13">2 Fish Tacos</p><span class="price p13"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
        <p class="item item-14">Chiles Rellenos</p><span class="price p14"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
        <p class="item item-15">Red Combo</p><span class="price p15"><span class="s1">$</span>7.95</span>
        <p class="item item-16">Green Combo</p><span class="price p16"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>
        <p class="item item-17">3 Rolled Tacos w/Guacamole</p><span class="price p17"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
        <p class="item item-18">Chimichanga, Rice & Beans</p><span class="price p18"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>
        <p class="item item-19">Carne Asada Burrito</p><span class="price p19"><span class="s1">$</span>7.19</span>
        <p class="item item-20">2 Tamales, Rice & Beans</p><span class="price p20"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>

        <h3 class="platter plat-4">Tacos</h3>
        <p class="platter-info info4tacos">Folded</p>

        <p class="item item-21">1 Chicken Taco</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
        <p class="item item-22">1 Beef</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
        <p class="item item-23">1 Carne Asada</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.61</span>
        <p class="item item-21">1 Fish</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
        <p class="item item-22">1 Carnitas</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
        <p class="item item-23">1 Adobada</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
        <p class="item item-23">1 Cabeza</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>

        <p class="platter-info info4tacos">Rolled</p>

        <p class="item item-21">3 Plain with Cheese</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.39</span>
        <p class="item item-22">3 Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.89</span>
        <p class="item item-23">3 Chicken w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.89</span>
        <p class="item item-21">3 Tacos w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>3.99</span>
        <p class="item item-22">12 Tacos w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>8.99</span>

        <h3 class="platter plat-7">Tortas</h3>

        <p class="item item-21">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
        <p class="item item-22">Machaca</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
        <p class="item item-23">Ham</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.61</span>
        <p class="item item-21">Chorizo</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
        <p class="item item-22">Chicken</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
        <p class="item item-23">Carnitas</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
        <p class="item item-23">Fish</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>

        <h3 class="platter plat-8">Breakfast Served Everyday</h3>
        <p class="platter-info info4breakfast">6am to 11am</p>

        <h3 class="platter plat-9">Breakfast Plates</h3>

        <p class="item item-21">Huevos Racheros</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>6.29</span>
        <p class="item item-22">Steaks Racheros</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
        <p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Ham</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="col-2">
    <h3 class="platter plat-2">Enchiladas</h3>

    <p class="item item-21">2 Cheese</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-22">2 Beef</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-23">2 Chicken</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-3">Side Orders</h3>

    <p class="item item-24">Carne Asada Fries</p><span class="price p24"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-25">Jalepenos</p><span class="price p25"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-26">Quesadilla</p><span class="price p26"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-27">Ham Quesadilla</p><span class="price p27"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-28">1/2 Pint of Beans</p><span class="price p28"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-29">1/2 Pint of rice</p><span class="price p29"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-30">Ham Quesadilla</p><span class="price p30"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-31">Super Nachos</p><span class="price p31"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-32">1 Tamale</p><span class="price p32"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-33">Extra Cheese Quacamole</p><span class="price p33"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-34">Supreme Quesadilla</p><span class="price p34"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-35">Chips and Quacamole</p><span class="price p35"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-36">1 Chiles Rellano</p><span class="price p36"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-37">Chips & Salsa</p><span class="price p37"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Churros</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Burrito Asada R&B</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-40">1/2 Pint of Beans</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-41">1/2 Pint of rice</p><span class="price p41"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
   </div> -->
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```